# How can I figure out how much weight this span could support?

Tags: design, pressure-treated, weight-capacity

I'm designing an outdoor bench. It will be made out of 1in plywood and pressure treated 2x4s. I'm wanting an 8ft length (give or take). The seat will be 7 2x4s. Can I get away with an open span? or do I need to add another bracing section?
[image: iso view]

Here's a fly around of the bench if that helps https://youtu.be/OLPQDtLKUG8

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I tried the sagulator, but it didn't have pressure treated as an option.

**UPDATE**

So I realized this design had two fatal flaws regardless of the weight on the seat.

1. There is no real horizontal shear support for the base
2. Having a long flat base as this does, will not sit well on an unlevel surface like my yard.

Here is what I ended up with. This thing could support an elephant!!
[image: Final Product]

Comment: There should not be any appreciable difference in strength between pressure treated and plain.

Comment: *"Can I get away with an open span?"* That depends on the expected loads. The maximum central load is the key one, people seated off to one side produce far less of a bending force on the wood, and two people sitting side by side can also be less (even if their weights total to slightly more than that of the person who might sit in the centre). Can I just check, is this for a domestic setting? If so it'll see lighter and more occasional use so I can't imagine this won't be fine. For a public setting it would be different, and how the ends were fixed might also have to be chosen with more care.

Comment: Plugging in some approximate numbers into the Sagulator I get what it classes as excessive load, and it would be for a shelf which just sits there holding books. For periodic loads things are slightly different, and how you feel about a slight bow (enough to be visible) would likely be different as well. It's a big deal visually if a shelf bows, not so much with a bench. Also here it might be felt that it provides a modicum of springiness which could be seen as a positive, not a negative (your call though).

Comment: Not sure what numbers you used in Sagulator, Graphus.  I used 96" span, 24" wide, 1.5" thick of douglas fir.  With 500 pounds of center load, or 1000 pounds of load spread evenly, I get a sag of 0.18, which is acceptable.

Comment: @LeeG I started with the assumption of a single person sitting centrally, guessed at the number of boards a person would weigh down on when seated (typical bum wouldn't scoot all the way to the back and weigh down there equally with the other boards), used a weight of 190 as a reasonable upper average (didn't want to assume fatties like me LOL) and then *didn't* assume Douglas fir which SPF might be if the OP had a lucky buy, instead the more likely pines. Got Excessive (~0.3") for the few pines I tried. Marginal for Doug fir. Acceptable for the spruce subspecies I tried.

Comment: fwiw, I wouldn't want splinters from PT in my nether regions. Strongly suggest you reconsider materials. (For example, redwood and cedar are highly rot-resistant, though not as strong as other options.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate the bench will have cushions on it.

Comment: Check out the Forestry Service's book: Wood Handbook - Wood as an Engineering Material. It contains information regarding shear and compression strength of various materials, fastenings and tons of other details. https://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/documnts/fplgtr/fpl_gtr190.pdf